# Chain Matrix Multiplication : Multiply Algorithm not working

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

I have implemented a chain matrix multiplication. Although I get correct chain order, but while doing actual multiplication, the given multiply algorithm is not working properly. My Java Code:-

```
package algopackage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChainMatrixMultiplication {

    static int s[][];

    static int x[][];

    static int y[][];

    public ChainMatrixMultiplication() {
    }

    static void chainMatrixMultiplication(int[] p) {
        boolean isFirst = false;
        int n = p.length-1;
        int m[][] = new int[n][n];
        s = new int[n][n];
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) 
            m[c][c] = 0; 
        for (int counter = 1; counter < n; counter++) {
            for (int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
                isFirst = false;
                int j = i + counter;
                for (int k = i; k < j && j < n; k++) {
                    int result = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i] * p[k+1] * p[j+1];
                    if (!isFirst) {
                        m[i][j] = result;
                        s[i][j] = k;
                        isFirst = true;
                    } else if (m[i][j] > result) {
                        m[i][j] = result;
                        s[i][j] = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int[][] matrixMultiply(List<Matrix> matrices, int s[][], int i ,int j) {
        if (i ==j) return matrices.get(i).getMatrix();
         else {
             int k = s[i][j];
             x = matrixMultiply(matrices, s, i, k);
             y = matrixMultiply(matrices, s, k+1, j);
             return mult(x,y);
        }
    }

    static int[][] mult(int[][] x, int[][] y) {
        int [][] result = new int[x.length][y[0].length];

        /* Loop through each and get product, then sum up and store the value */
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < y[0].length; j++) { 
                for (int k = 0; k < x[0].length; k++) { 
                    result[i][j] += x[i][k] * y[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p[] = {5,4,6,2};
        List<Matrix> matrices = new ArrayList<Matrix>();
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(5,4);
        int arr[] = {1,2,40,2,3,29,10,21,11,120,23,90,24,12,11,1,11,45,23,21};
        m1.addElementsToMatrix(5, 4, arr);
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(4,6);
        int arr1[] = {1,1,1,2,3,12,12,3,10,12,12,29,22,11,22,11,11,11,13,1,2,12,4,2};
        m2.addElementsToMatrix(4, 6, arr1);
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(6,2);
        int arr2[] = {1,1,12,3,22,11,13,1,2,12,12,12};
        m3.addElementsToMatrix(6, 2, arr2);
        matrices.add(m1);
        matrices.add(m2);
        matrices.add(m3);
        chainMatrixMultiplication(p);
        matrixMultiply(matrices,s,0,2);
    }

}

class Matrix {

       private final int[][] matrix;

       public Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
            this.matrix = new int[rows][cols];
       }

       public void addElementsToMatrix(int rows, int cols, int[] arr) {
           int counter = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                   matrix[i][j] = arr[counter++];
               }
           }

       }

       public int[][] getMatrix() {
           return matrix;
       }
}
```

In the above code matrixMultiply() function is throwing exception. Exception is caused as matrices are not being multiplied as expected. As recursion is not behaving as expected. I am missing something in this code. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the correctness of your code, but looking at the matrix multiplication output when you multiply matrix of dimension a*b and c*d after you multiply, you get a matrix of dimension a*d there by changing

```
for (int k = 0; k < x[0].length; k++) {
```

to

```
for (int k = 0; k < y[0].length; k++) {
```

should resolve the problem.

Comment: Problem is due to matrixMultiply() function in which the matrices are not getting multiplied in proper order. mult() function is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 x = matrixMultiply(matrices, s, i, k);   // call A
 y = matrixMultiply(matrices, s, k+1, j); // call B
 return mult(x,y);
```

looks like it should multiply the result of call A by the result of call B. But in general, it doesn't.

`x` is not local, call B will usually overwrite it, except when call B immediately hits the base case.

This sort of thing tends to happen when you pass data around "to the side", not as function parameter or function return value. It is not reasonable to avoid that kind of data flow all the time, but you should avoid it here, especially since it's not even what you wanted.

Comment: Yes...But I am not getting what you mean by pass data around "to the side".Also can you please suggest change which will make it behave properly? Thanks!

Comment: @Batman "not as function parameter or function return value". Just make `x` and `y` local.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.I didn't pay attention to the static x & y. Thanks again!